# Hiding shapes depending on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I am using the following code to hide/unhide some shapes based on a cell value. The hiding/showing is working however the shapes work as links and when I click on some of them it just changes and starts showing all the shapes at the same time.
Is there a better code to do this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$50" Then
        'AAA
        Shapes("XXX1").Visible = Target.Value = "ABC"
        Shapes("XXX2").Visible = Target.Value = "ABC"
        Shapes("XXX3").Visible = Target.Value = "ABC"
       'BBB
        Shapes("YYY1").Visible = Target.Value = "DEF"
       'CCC
        Shapes("ZZZ1").Visible = Target.Value = "GHI"
        Shapes("ZZZ2").Visible = Target.Value = "GHI"
        Shapes("ZZZ3").Visible = Target.Value = "GHI"

    End If
End Sub
```